# How can I get a static SQLite database to show up in my listView

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-listview, static-data

I'll start off by listing the code i have thus far...

This is my main Activity class:

```
public class SQLiteDatabaseMain extends Activity
{
    ListView list;
    DatabaseHelper helper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DatabaseAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        init();
    }

    public void init()
    {
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        helper.populateGrocery(db);

    }

}
```

This is my DatabaseHelper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "grocerystoretest.db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "grocerystoreitems";
private static final String GROCERY_KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String GROCERY_KEY_TYPE = "type";
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;

SQLiteDatabaseMain sqlMain = new SQLiteDatabaseMain();

public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "
            + DATABASE_TABLE
            + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, type TEXT);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2)
{
    // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_NAME);

}

public void insert(String name, String type)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("name", name);
    cv.put("type", type);

    getWritableDatabase().insert(DATABASE_TABLE, "name", cv);
}

public void update(String id, String name, String type)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    String[] args =
    { id };

    cv.put("name", name);
    cv.put("type", type);

    getWritableDatabase().update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, "_ID=?", args);
}

public void delete(String id, String name, String type)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    String[] args =
    { id };

    cv.put("name", name);
    cv.put("type", type);

    getWritableDatabase().delete(DATABASE_TABLE, "_ID=?", args);
}

public void populateGrocery(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    ArrayList<GroceryObj> groceryArrayList;
    groceryArrayList = buildGroceryArrayList();
    String insertStmt = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < groceryArrayList.size(); i++)
    {
        insertStmt = "INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                + GROCERY_KEY_NAME + ", " + GROCERY_KEY_TYPE + ") "
                + "VALUES (\"" + groceryArrayList.get(i).getName()
                + "\", \"" + groceryArrayList.get(i).getType() + "\");";
        db.execSQL(insertStmt);
    }
}

private ArrayList<GroceryObj> buildGroceryArrayList()
{
    ArrayList<GroceryObj> aL = new ArrayList<GroceryObj>();
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try
    {
        Context context;
        context = sqlMain.getApplicationContext();

        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream raw = context.getAssets().open("default_grocerystore.xml");
        Document dom = builder.parse(raw);
        Element root = (Element) dom.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList groceryItems = ((Document) root)
                .getElementsByTagName("grocery");
        for (int i = 0; i < groceryItems.getLength(); i++)
        {
            String name = null;
            String type = null;
            Node item = groceryItems.item(i);
            NodeList groceryItem = item.getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < groceryItem.getLength(); j++)
            {
                Node nodeItem = groceryItem.item(j);
                String nodeName = nodeItem.getNodeName();
                if (nodeName.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
                {
                    name = nodeItem.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                } else if (nodeName.equalsIgnoreCase("type"))
                {
                    type = nodeItem.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                }
            }
            aL.add(new GroceryObj(name, type));
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return aL;
}

public String getName(Cursor c)
{
    return (c.getString(1));
}

public String getType(Cursor c)
{
    return (c.getString(3));
}

}
```

This is my GroceryObj class:

```
public class GroceryObj
{

private String name = "";
private String type = "";

public GroceryObj(String name, String type)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
}

public String getName()
{
    return (name);
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getType()
{
    return (type);
}

public void setType(String type)
{
    this.type = type;
}

}
```

My DatabaseAdapter class is blank right now. This is what I need to figure out!:

```
public class DatabaseAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{

public DatabaseAdapter(Context context, Cursor c)
{
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
{

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
{
    return null;
}

}
```

Then I have an xml file that stores all of the grocery items by name and type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<default_grocerystore>
    <grocery>
            <name>Bread</name>
            <type>Bakery</type>
    </grocery>
    <grocery>
            <name>Rolls</name>
            <type>Bakery</type>
    </grocery>
    <grocery>
            <name>Juice</name>
            <type>Beverages</type>
    </grocery>
    <grocery>
            <name>Soda</name>
            <type>Beverages</type>
    </grocery>
</default_grocerystore>
```

And finally I have a row.xml that is just two textViews that are to display the name and type of each item in each row of my ListView.

My main.xml is just a TextView and a listview.

What I'm really stuck on is the Adapter. Ive used database adapters before to insert rows into a database via editTexts and a holder object but Ive never just taken a static database and had it converted to each row to View via my listView. Anyone have any pointers on what is needed to get my database viewed via a listView?? Any help would be greatly appreciated because I am completely stumped here. Ive been racking my brain for the past few hours trying to find out how to do this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: From what you've said, I don't understand why you think you need a custom adapter...  a `SimpleCursorAdapter` will work just fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: remove this line `helper.populateGrocery(db);` from your init and move it to `public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` in your DatabaseHelper class after the create statement. This will make it so you only populate your Database once and not every time you start your app.

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleAdapter` is meant for static data, so your performance may vary if you are going to use dynamic data. Other way is probably to use a different type of adapter if you want to use dynamic data, such as `ArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a CursorAdapter, a simple ArrayAdapter will do. Just store your results from your database query in an ArrayList(which you're already doing), and then pass that list into the constructor of your Adapter. Your array adapter must be able to accept an arraylist of type GroceryObj, then you could call GroceryObj.getName() or getType() to fill your ListView